# Can I solve this limit?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'd just like to make sure I'm right about this. I'm pretty sure this limit is unsolvable, or at least not with easy algebra.

$$\lim_{x\to 5}\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-5}$$

I tried completing the square to factor out the $x-5$ but that renders a fraction. So am I right to say this limit does not exist?

Comment: You don't even need to factorise it, really, just show that the polynomial in the numerator evaluates to something other than $0$ at $x=5$.

Comment: Why would you complete the square?  The numerator immediately factors as $(x-2)(x-3)$.  Use rational roots test if it isn't immediate for you...

Comment: Are you asked to prove that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: Misakov: No, just note if it does not.

Comment: G. H. Faust: Oh yeah, that should have been obvious to me.

Answer (score 7):

$$\lim_{x\to 5^+}\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-5}=\frac{6}{0^+}=+\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to 5^-}\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-5}=\frac{6}{0^-}=-\infty$$

So limit does not exist!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If $x-5\ne0,$
$$\frac{x^2-5x+6}{x-5}=x+\frac6{x-5}$$

Now if $x\to5,x\ne5$